# Why can't I write with the event-properties in NLog?

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to create a CSV file with multiple columns using NLog. There are not enough layouts for this (more than one message). I want to use event-properties for this.

```
   sendEmailLogger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "01.01.2018");
    Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, "CSVSendLogger", "custom value");
    theEvent.Properties["xxx"] = 1234;
    log.Log(theEvent);
```

NLog config file

```
    <target  name="CSVSendLogger" xsi:type="File"
    fileName="${logDirectory}/send_log/log_mail.csv">
    <layout  xsi:type="CSVLayout">
    <column name="Column1" layout="${event-properties:item=xxx}" />
    <column name="Column2" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
```

[image]

Comment: do you need a csv file with dynamic amount of columns? (one for each event-property?)

Comment: Try simple file-logging without `CsvLayout`, and instead just use `${logger}${message}${all-event-properties}` when you see the wanted output, then convert to `CsvLayout` and extract the wanted properties.